# Grails - Validation of embedded object attributes only while updating

Tags: grails

I have a grails domain class with an embedded object, I want to validate the embedded object's attributes only while updating.

I know I can do this on a normal grails domain class by using a custom validator and checking if the domain's class id is not null. 
I can't do this because of the lack of an id on an embedded object.

There is a little example of what I want to do.

```
//This is on domain/somePackage/A.groovy
class A{
    B embeddedObject

    static embedded = ['embeddedObject']

    static constraints = {
        embeddedObject.attribute validator:{val, obj-> //The app fails to start when this code is added!!
            if(obj.id && !val) //if the id is not null it means the object it's updating...
                return 'some.error.code'
        }
    }

}


//this class is on src/groovy/somePackage/B.groovy
class B{
    String attribute

    static constraints={
        attribute validator:{val,obj->
            if(obj.id && !val) //This will fail too! because the lack of an id on this object....
                return 'some.error.code'
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the id of the 'parent' on the embedded object??
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

way too complicated:

```
class A{
    B embeddedObject

    static embedded = ['embeddedObject']

    static constraints = {
        embeddedObject validator:{ val, obj ->
            if( obj.id && !val.attribute )
                return 'some.error.code'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, yesterday, after trying I figured it out.